# Copying a Portion of Graphics Memory to RAM Java

Tags: java, graphics, ram, copying

I'm trying to get a portion of the Graphics Memory, and copy what is on it to normal RAM. Is there a possible way to do this with Java? I've searched around a bit, but to no avail. Also, I would assume it depends on your GPU / Chipset, so how would you detect that as well?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why on earth would you want that in Java?

Comment: I need to get the images in order to create a video recording mechanism. The one I have is terrible and inefficient, I thought this might be better.

Comment: Don't use Java for this.  You need platform dependent code to talk to the operating system.

Comment: Even then, is it possible? Could I use Java to call the appropriate methods / functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use JNA to make method calls to shared libraries.

You can use Unsafe.copyMemory to copy memory from one place to another, or to an object.  Note: it is unsafe in the sense that memcpy is unsafe. ;)